# Retrieve Array Of Documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I have a MongoDB Document like as follows

```
{
"_id":1,
"name":"XYZ"

ExamScores:[
{ExamName:"Maths", UnitTest:1, Score:100},
{ExamName:"Maths", UnitTest:2, Score:80},
{ExamName:"Science", UnitTest:1, Score:90}
]
}
```

I Need to retrieve this document so that it has to show only Maths Array. Like as follows

```
{
    "_id":1,
    "name":"XYZ"

    ExamScores:[
    {ExamName:"Maths", UnitTest:1, Score:100},
    {ExamName:"Maths", UnitTest:2, Score:80},        
    ]
    }
```

How Can I Do That ?

Answer (score 2):

As @karin states there is no, normal, in query method of doing this.

In version 2.2 you can use `$elemMatch` to project the first matching result from `ExamScores` but you cannot get multiple.

That being said, the aggregation framework can do this:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$ExamScores'},
    {$match: {'ExamScores.ExamName':"Maths"}},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', name: '$name', ExamScores: {$push: '$ExamScores'}}}
])
```

Something like that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before [MongoDB query to limit values based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845191/mongodb-query-to-limit-values-based-on-condition), the only answer there says it is not possible, but that there is a [request](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142) to implement that.